# I keep getting debugging errors for my C++ function. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong

Tags: c++, function

**Hi, I'm very new to programming, for this program i am supposed to be able to calculate someone's monthly charges by using functions. When I compile it it's fine, but when I try to debug it says I've failed so I can't tell what I'm doing wrong. Here is my code:**

//this program calculates a user's monthly charges

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std;

//function prototypes
void showpackage();
void calculatePkg_A (int,int,int);
void calculatePkg_B (int,int,int);
void calculatePkg_C (int,int,int);


int main ()
{
    int inputPackage; //package choice
    double inputHours; //number of hours


    //constants for package choice
    const int pkg_A = '1' ,
               pkg_B = '2',
               pkg_C = '3';
     const char quit_choice = 'Q' || 'q';
    //constants for cost of package
    const int cost_A = 15,
              cost_B = 20,
              cost_C = 25;
    //constants for package access time
    const int hours_A = 50,
              hours_B = 100,
              hours_C = 150;
    cout << fixed << showpoint << setprecision (2);
    do
    { //display package options. 
        showpackage();
        cin >> inputPackage;

        //validate package selection
        while (inputPackage < pkg_A || inputPackage > pkg_C || inputPackage != quit_choice )
        {
            cout << "Please enter a valid package choice:";
            cin >> inputPackage;
        }
        //If user does not want to quit, proceed.
if (inputHours < 0 || inputHours > 720 || inputPackage != quit_choice)
        {
            //get the number of hours used
            cout << "How many hours were used?";
            cin >> inputHours;

                //display the total charges
                switch (inputPackage)
                {
                case pkg_A:
                    calculatePkg_A (cost_A, hours_A, inputHours);
                    break;
                case pkg_B:
                    calculatePkg_B (cost_B, hours_B, inputHours);
                    break;
                case pkg_C:
                    calculatePkg_C (cost_C, hours_C, inputHours);
                    break;
                }
            }
    } while (inputPackage != quit_choice);


            return 0;
}


//definition of function showPackage which displays package options

void showPackage()
{cout <<"An Internet service provider has three different packages for its customers: \n"
<<"1.Package A: For $15 per month with 50 Hours of access provided, additional hours \n"
<<"are $2.00 per hour over 50 hours.\n"
<<"2.Package B: For $20 per month with 100 Hours of access provided, additional hours \n"
<<"are $1.50 per hour over 100 hours.\n"
<<"3.Package C: For $25 per month with 150 Hours of access provided, additional hours \n"
<<"are $1.00 per hour over 150 hours.\n"
<<"Enter your choice either 1,2, or 3:";
}

//defintion of function calculatePkg_A. Displays total charges.


void calculatePkg_A (int cost_A, int hours_A, int inputHours)
    {
        cout << "The total charges are $"
             << (cost_A += (inputHours - hours_A) * 2) << endl;
}

//
//defintion of function calculatePkg_B. Displays total charges.
//

void calculatePkg_B (int cost_B, int hours_B, int inputHours)
    {
        cout << "The total charges are $"
             << (cost_B += (inputHours - hours_B) * 1.5) << endl;
}

//defintion of function calculatePkg_C. Displays total charges.


void calculatePkg_C (int cost_C, int hours_C, int inputHours)
    {
        cout << "The total charges are $"
             << (cost_C += (inputHours - hours_C)) << endl;
}
```

**But whenever i try to debug it I keep getting the error message:**

```
1>Program5.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "void __cdecl calculatePkg_C(double,double,double)" (?calculatePkg_C@@YAXNNN@Z) referenced in function _main
1>Program5.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "void __cdecl showpackage(void)" (?showpackage@@YAXXZ) referenced in function _main
    1>C:\Users\charlotte\Desktop\program5\Debug\program5.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 2 unresolved externals
```

Comment: you have a linking problem, it's a problem between your code and the library that you are using, you need to specify what compiler, OS, library and version you are using

Comment: By the way, you can't do this: `const char quit_choice = 'Q' || 'q';`.  It may be easiest to use `toupper` or `tolower` before you test a choice, with the assumption that a choice is always uppercase or lowercase.

Comment: @paddy well, technically you can, but it's equivalent to `const char quit_choice = char(1)`...  so not much use...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First error is that the compiler decided you need to pass `double` types to `calculatePkg_C`.  It expects:

```
calculatePkg_C(double,double,double)
```

But yours is:

```
calculatePkg_C(int,int,int)
```

You need to ask yourself why this would be.  You've declared it at the top, and defined it below correctly.  Is there something you are not showing?  I notice you are passing `inputHours` which is a `double`.  Try casting that as an `int`.

The other error is `showPackage`.  Your declaration (and usage) has the wrong capitalisation.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit The declaration and usage both have a lowercase 'p'.  The definition has an uppercase 'p'.  Given the capitalisation of other functions, I decided that the declaration is wrong, but I could have just said the definition is wrong.  That's up to the author's preference.

Comment: Oh, so it does (the definition). OK

Answer (score 1):

The error message tells us that you've declared `calculatePkg_C(double,double,double)` but you implemented `calculatePkg_C(int,int,int)`. Change the prototype in the definition and it should work. Also, look for where the function with this prototype is declared.

Answer (score 0):

You need to examine the build properties for each of your build types. The source file(s) that contain your `caclulatePkg_C()` and `showpackage()` methods is in your Release configuration, but not your Debug configuration.

Answer (score 0):

I'm shure that you declare your three function as taking three int parameters in their prototypes:

```
void calculatePkg_A (int,int,int);
void calculatePkg_B (int,int,int);
void calculatePkg_C (int,int,int);
```

but you surely pass it a double as third parameter, because you declare:

```
double inputHours; //number of hours
```

I don't recommend any cast here, your better declare it as integer if you must keep function prototypes.

In showpackage implementation, remember C/C++ has a case sensitive sintax, thus you should write:

```
//definition of function showPackage which displays package options

void showPackage()
{
...
}
```